# Convergence in $L^2$ implies uniform convergence for the normalized functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Good morning,

I've recently came across this question and, although it seems logical for me to be true, I still can't come up with a satisfactory answer.

The question is the following: suppose that you have a sequence $\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}\subset L^2([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ that converges in $L^2$ to some $f\in L^2([0,1],\mathbb{R})$. Define then $e_n:= \frac{f_n}{|f_n|}$ and, similarly, $e=\frac{f}{|f|}$.

**Q:** Is it true that $e_n\to e$ in $L^\infty([0,1],\mathbb{R})$?

My guess is yes because $|e_n-e|=2-2\cos(\theta_n)$, where $\theta_n$ is the angle between $f_n$ and $f$ and, since $f_n\to f$ a.e., then $\theta\to 0$ a.e. However, I feel that this answer is not complete, and I fear I'm missing potentially something.

Thank you in advance for your replies,

Guido

Comment: It's not so much incomplete as totally wrong. Two mega-errors: Convergence in $L^2$ does not imply convergence almost everywhere, and convergence almost everywhere does not imply uniform convergence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the sequence of characteristic functions in $L^2([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ given by

$$f_1 = \chi_{\left[0, \frac12\right]}, f_2 = \chi_{\left[\frac12, 1\right]}$$

$$f_3 = \chi_{\left[0, \frac13\right]}, f_4 = \chi_{\left[\frac13, \frac23\right]}, f_5 = \chi_{\left[\frac23, 1\right]}$$

$$f_6 = \chi_{\left[0, \frac14\right]}, f_7 = \chi_{\left[\frac14, \frac24\right]}, f_7 = \chi_{\left[\frac24, \frac34\right]}, f_9 = \chi_{\left[\frac34, 1\right]}$$

and so on. We have that $f_n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$ in $L^2$.

However, the sequence $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty = (f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ does not converge in $L^\infty$. Moreover, it does not even converge almost everywhere.

Comment: Uhm... Fair enough! and nice counterexample. Ok so $L^\infty$ is a too strong topology. From your example, however, $e_n\to 0$ in $L^2$ (obviously). Do you think that, in general $e_n\to e$ in $L^2$ instead? Ps. I accept the answer and thank you!

Comment: @guidogiuliani No. Consider the constant functions $f_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. We have $f_n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$ in $L^2$. However, $e_n = (-1)^n$ does not converge in $L^2$ (or in any other way). Btw. I realized that I interpreted the problem as $e_n = \operatorname{sgn} f_n$. Perhaps you meant that $f_n, f \ne 0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Indeed, it seems from your counterexamples that the problem is the convergence to zero, and in fact $e_n$ is not well defined where $f_n=0$. Do you think that it changes something requiring that $f\neq 0$ a.e.? Looking back  this seems important.

Comment: @guidogiuliani To fix my first counterexample for $L^\infty$, consider $\tilde{f_n} = 2f_n - 1$, which looks the same as $f_n$, only now it is $-1$ where $f_n$ was $0$. We have $\tilde{f_n} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} -1$ in $L^2$, but again $\tilde{e_n} = \tilde{f_n}$ does not converge in $L^\infty$.

Comment: I believe the $f_n \xrightarrow{L^2} f \implies e_n \xrightarrow{L^2} e $ holds if we additionally assume that $f_n, f \in L^{\infty}[0,1]$. In that case we can use the inequality $$\left|\frac{f}{|f|} - \frac{g}{|g|}\right| \le 4\frac{|f-g|}{|f| + |g|}$$
Otherwise I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I would upvote more if I could, but unfortunately I cannot.